# Why does a conditionally rendered React component flicker on refresh but not an inline version of the same component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am stumped. Why does one flicker and not the other?
This is a contrived example to force a screen refresh.

See the full source on [this Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@gollyjer/conditional-render-flicker) for the `useInterval` and `useForceUpdate` hooks.

- Screen
  [image]
- Code

  ```js
  const App = () => {
    const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
    useInterval(() => {
      forceUpdate();
    }, 1000);

    const imageSource = {
      uri:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485832329521-e944d75fa65e?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D',
    };

    const shouldRenderImage = true;

    const MyImage = () => (
      <>
        {shouldRenderImage && <Image style={styles.image} source={imageSource} />}
      </>
    );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Conditional Inside Component</Text>
        <MyImage />

        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Conditional Render Component</Text>
        <>
          {shouldRenderImage && (
            <Image style={styles.image} source={imageSource} />
          )}
        </>
      </View>
    );
  };
  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using functional component.So everytime your state changes,
all your functions will initialise again. So whenever the state changes, your Image component will Reinitialise, (It will mount again)

```
 const MyImage = () => (
    <>
      {shouldRenderImage && <Image style={styles.image} source={imageSource} />}
    </>
  );
```

To minimise reinitialising on every re-render we can use `useCallback` hook from react.

```js
import  React, {useCallback} from 'react';
```

```js
const MyImage = useCallback(() => (
    <>
      {shouldRenderImage && <Image style={styles.image} source={imageSource} />}
    </>
  ),[shouldRenderImage]);
```

Comment: Yes! That makes perfect sense. In the first version, every time a render triggers the function is called which *creates a new copy* of the component. React sees something new and kills the old and shows the new. In the second it is either showing or not showing the same entity. Thanks @Sarmad Shah 

Comment: Thinking about this more... Another, even easier way is to call `MyImage` inside the App render. Like `{MyImage()}`. That essentially does the same thing doesn't it?

Comment: you should use `useCallback` everytime you encounter something similar, as with `useCallback` you can control when the component should actually re-render or reinitialise, in your case i have added `shouldrenderImage`, as a dependancy, so everytime `shouldrenderImage` changes, it will re-render, Same with `useMemo`